# Xamarin forms select carousel item

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I am learning Xamarin, I would like to get the value of the carousel item selected. I cannot add ItemSelected as in a listview.

Here my Xaml code :

```
<CarouselView x:Name="NewsList"  >
    <CarouselView.ItemTemplate >
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout>
                <Frame HasShadow="True"
                       BorderColor="DarkGray"
                       CornerRadius="5"
                       Margin="20"

                       HeightRequest="300"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"
                       VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand">
                                            <StackLayout>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding NewsName}"
                               FontAttributes="Bold"
                               FontSize="Large"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center"
                               VerticalOptions="Center" />
                                                <Image Source="{Binding NewsImageUrl}"
                               Aspect="Fill"
                               HeightRequest="150"
                               WidthRequest="150"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center" />
                                                <Label Text="{Binding ProviderAndDate}"
                               HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                                            </StackLayout>
                                        </Frame>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
</CarouselView>
```

Here is the function I would like to use once my item is selected: Get the value of NewsName and ProviderAndDate

```
  private void OnFrameTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SelectedNewsName" + "SelectedNewsProviderAndDate");
        }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CarouselView is sort of a different control when it comes to visualization and events than a ListView so you will have to come up with sort of a different solution too

The easiest way to do something similar to a selected item event here would need customization from your side to add the event in.

A good workaround would be just using the CurrentItem property or passing a CommandParameter on the Tap of a Frame!

```
<StackLayout>
   <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
   <TapGestureRecognizer Command="{Binding CarouselItemTapped,Source={x:Reference currentPage}}" CommandParameter="{Binding .}"/>
   </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
<Frame ...... />
```

And then give your current contentpage a `x:Name`

```
<ContentPage ..... X:Name="currentPage"
```

Now in your `xaml.cs`

```
Public ICommand CarouselItemTapped{ get; set; }
```

In the Constructor:

```
CarouselItemTapped= new Xamarin.Forms.Command((selectItem)=>{//Perform action here});
```

Feel free to get back if you have questions

More about Commands: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/data-binding/commanding

More about CarouselView: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/carouselview/

Answer (score 0):

Late but it might help someone. The one who is using BindingContext to bind the data, they can get tapped model as shown below.

```
private void OnFrameTapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var frame = sender as Frame;
    var x = frame.BindingContext as YOURMODEL;
}
```